# Repeat HTTP requests until 404 error is returned

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I would like to send http requests until one of them responds with `error 404`.

There are 21 pages and I have something like this:

```
_getAll = function () {

var promises = [];
var pages = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21];
angular.forEach(pages, function (page) {
    var deffered = $q.defer();
        $http({
            url: 'http://api.tvmaze.com/shows?page=' + page,
            method: 'GET'
        }).
            success(function (data) {
                console.log("OK")
                deffered.resolve(data);
            }).
            error(function (error) {
                deffered.reject(error);
                console.log(error.status);
            });
        promises.push(deffered.promise)
    })
    return $q.all(promises);
},
```

But if I try to get http://api.tvmaze.com/shows?page=22 it returns `404 error`.

So is there an option to make `http` request until one of them returns `404`. while looping or somehow else?

Comment: cancel the promise? - http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2731-canceling-a-promise-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: http://api.tvmaze.com/shows?page=22  This is returning an empty array and not 404.

Answer (score 1):

These calls are asynchronous so a while loop would try to make calls to 1000s of pages in just a couple ms before you'd even load the first page. You need to wait for each page to complete before loading the next page.

One way to do this is to make a function to get a page and trigger it with the next page number each time you successfully load a page. Once you hit an error trigger a final success callback and pass the data back.

```
_getAll = function(callback) {

    var pageData=[];

    function getPage(page) {
        $http({
            url: 'http://api.tvmaze.com/shows?page=' + page,
            method: 'GET'
        }).
        success(function (data) {
            pageData.push(data);
            //get next page
            getPage(page + 1);
            console.log("OK")
        }).
        error(function (error) {
            //Hit an error. All done. Trigger callback.
            callback(pageData);
            console.log(error.status);
        });
    }

    //get first page
    getPage(0);
}

//usage:

_getAll(function(data){
    //this function will trigger once we get an error
    //data will be an array of all of the pages data
   console.log(data); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$q.all` with proper error handling will allow you to do it. Here is the code with explanation below:

```
_getAll = function() {

    var pages = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21];
    return $q.all(pages.map(function(page) {
        return $http({
            url: 'http://api.tvmaze.com/shows?page=' + page,
            method: 'GET'
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        }, angular.noop);
    }))
    .then(function(data) {
        data.pop();
        return data;
    });
};
```

Note, `angular.noop` in `then` callback of the individual requests. It basically the way to handle failed request when there are not more pages (status 404). When you reach in this error callback (which does nothing) and since it does nothing it means that you sort of recovered from error situation and all previous successful request data will propagate further. In the next `then` down the chain we need to remove the last `undefined` element (the one returned by `angular.noop` for 404 page), so that resulting array of data doesn't have meaningless undefined values as the last element.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/CR711Js1KvrvnvKDonXK?p=preview